# Highlight keywords in math mode?

Tags: emacs, highlighting, auctex

I am using Emacs+Auctex. I need additional highlighting in math mode. How can I force Emacs to highlight braces and some commands (like \quad) inside math mode with different color?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67365/more-fine-grained-syntax-highlighting-in-emacs-auctex